# What are the Firebase reserved names?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

Reading the docs about creating [custom claims in Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims), we can see there are limitations on what we can put into the JWT token custom claims:

> The custom claims object should not contain any [OIDC](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) reserved key names or **Firebase reserved names**. Custom claims payload must not exceed 1000 bytes.

Although we can follow the link to find what the [OIDC](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) reserved names, the Firebase reserved names are not listed, neither I was able to find it on code or on another doc.

Where can I find these names so I won't collide with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can find in the source code of FirebaseUserManager.java, those are the reserved words:

```java
 static final List<String> RESERVED_CLAIMS = ImmutableList.of(
      "amr", "at_hash", "aud", "auth_time", "azp", "cnf", "c_hash", "exp", "iat",
      "iss", "jti", "nbf", "nonce", "sub", "firebase");
```